# Directed distance calculation in a rectangle

Tags: vector-spaces

[image]

This picture demonstrates my problem, I want to know the base vectors for the line B to D.
My first attempt got me this:
$$e_1=-\frac{1}{2}f_1-f_2$$
$$e_2=\frac{1}{2}f_2-f_1$$
$$BD=f_1+f_2$$ but that is wrong.

Comment: Isn't the vector running from B to D $ \ (- \ f_1) + \ f_2 \ $ ?

Comment: Pehaps you meant $BD=f_2 - f_1$?

Comment: If you're looking for expressing $BD$ using $e_1$ and $e_2$, you can do it by solving a system of two linear equations with two unknowns to obtain $BD = -\frac{2}{5}e_1 + \frac{6}{5}e_2$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you saying you want to write the line $BD$ as a linear combination of $e_1$ and $e_2$?

From your picture it looks like you've got your last line backwards, shouldn't it be $BD=-f_1+f_2$?  Now you just want $f_1$ and $f_2$ each in terms of $e_1$ and $e_2$ (which you should be able to do by rearranging/adding the first two equations you wrote) and then substitute that into your last equation.